# How to terminate a thread from outside or use input in multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm currently working on the client part in a client-server socket programming, in order
to collect user input and receiving incoming messages from server at the same time (doesn't want to be stuck at input and not receiving or vice versa), i decided to use thread at first it worked pretty good, i'm currently implementing a timeout function e.g. closing the entire client side without manually typing input and couldn't do so (the timeout timing is calculated in the server and server can send a message), so i changed my thread to multiprocessing it can be terminated but it shows a EOF Error when it reads an input.

Just wondering is there a way to run my input_command() function at the same time as receiving messages and being able to terminate both?

```
def input_command():
    
    while login:
        
        command = input()
        command_word = command.split(' ')
        
        if command == 'logout':
            clientSocket.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
            print('user has logged out')
            break
        elif command == 'whoelse':
            clientSocket.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            clientSocket.send('giberish'.encode('utf-8'))
    clientSocket.close()


server_port = int(sys.argv[1])

serverName = 'localhost'

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect((serverName, server_port))

login = False
once = False

while True:    
    received_message_encrypted = clientSocket.recv(1024)
    received_message = received_message_encrypted.decode('utf-8')
    if received_message == 'bye':
        clientSocket.close()
        login = False
        thread_input.terminate()
        break

    if login == True and once == False:
        once = True
        thread_input = multiprocessing.Process(target=input_command)
        thread_input.start()
```

Answer (score -2):

use .close instead of .terminate in process

Comment: Doesn't solve the EOF error though

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30338587)

Comment: @NO_NAME It does attempt to answer the question. It might not be detailed enough, but in that case you should downvote, not delete. See [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4284627).

Comment: @DonaldDuck I stand by my assessment that this is much better suited to be a comment than an answer. It is just a half of a sentence that points out some flaw in the code, without an indication that it has any potential to fix the actual problem. See an answer to the question you've brought up: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287565/3052438